# iOS 11: backBarButtonItem issue after dismissView Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I am facing an issue with navigationBar's backBarButtonItem in iOS 11 in all my apps. After launch the backBarButtonItem is at the right place but when I present a controller say Controller_B over present view controller say Controller_A and then dismiss the presented controller(Controller_B) then the backBarButtonItem on Controller_A get changes as you can see in the images:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide code of adding back button.

Comment: It's by default backBarButton item. I have just removed the backbar button title.

Comment: check if you are adding and removing a controller from right place, i.e. the same superclass.

Comment: Sure I checked it. I have added my view controller on navigationController as root view controller then presented over my current controller. Thanks for the response @KrutikaSonawala

Comment: It is better if you put some code of navigation & removal of it.

Comment: Sure @KrutikaSonawala:

UIViewController *src = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
ViewController *alert = [[ViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *alertNavigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:alert];
 [src presentViewController:alertNavigation animated:YES completion:nil];

Dismiss code:
[self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: Here what i think is; you are creating a new object with UINavigationController and dismissing from self.navigationController. Both are different objects. try making a navigation controller global that may achieve your task. or initiate self.navigationController with this root view contorller.

Comment: Sorry @KrutikaSonawala, The dismiss code is written on the presented controller so it will get the instance of presented navigation controller.